# How to fetch data from Bloomberg Hypermedia API using Biztalk?

Tags: biztalk, bloomberg

Does Biztalk natively or through plugins support fetching market data from Bloomberg Hypermedia API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear what sort of API's they expose.

> Data License supports multiple technologies including SPARQL, RStudio, Python and Jupyter and can output Tidy Data as CSV, JSON, Turtle or XML files.

BizTalk can certainly do CSV, JSON or XML, and can communicate with SOAP or REST API services, so if it is either of those, then yes, BizTalk can natively fetch data from those.